# WooCommerce variations tab doesn't display on admin side

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I added 70 products on my website with multiple variations. But now I need to change the price and when I click on the variations tab, my variations doesn't display.

Can it be a bug with the JavaScript or something?

Comment: First, I would check that the variations exists in the database - "select post_title from wp_posts where post_type = 'product_variation';

Comment: Hi, yes the variations exist on the database and it even display on the site. It is written 2 variations. They exist but they don't display, they are like hidden.

Comment: The variations are loaded by an AJAX request (action = 'woocommerce_load_variations'). Using your browser's network tool check if this AJAX request is sent. Check the response. It should be an HTML fragment.